# Increase and decrease the Premined balance supply on polygon-edge based POS enabled blockchain?

Tags: polygon

Hy Helpers,

I have a query regarding my polygon-edge POS enabled network that I wanted to increase & decrease the supply of Premined tokens, how can this be possible?
If any idea or suggestions regarding this , do let me know
Thanks